# Excel Macro loading Arrays

Tags: excel, vba

I am not sure how to phrase the question, but I have come up against an issue where I need to load a list of names from a group of sheets into seperate arrays.

For example, `Sheet 1`, `Column A` has 10 names to be loaded into `array1`, `Sheet 2`, `Column A` has 14 names to be loaded into `array2`.

I know this could be hard coded into a macro to load them all but the list of names is not a fixed length and shy of a lot of code I was wondering if this could be shortened.

The way that my mind would tell me to do this is below.

```
Dim tarray1 As Variant
Dim tarray2 As Variant
Dim tarray3 As Variant

For f = 1 To 3

    Sheets("Region " & f).Select
    With ActiveSheet
        lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        tarray& f = ActiveSheet.Range("A2:A" & lastrow)
    End With


Next
```

The actual sheet in question has 10 seperate sheets to have the names read in going from Region 1 to 10. So there will be 10 seperate tarrays. This is done for reporting purposes and will be passed back and forth around the sheets.

However `tarray & f` is obviously not valid and will throw up compile errors.

Can anyone think of a way to get around this?

Hope someone can help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following routine shows you how to use a jagged array of variants which I believe is the technique you need.

I have loaded different numbers of cells from the the first ten rows of a worksheet to TArray.  I use Debug.Print to show how to access the elements.

```
Sub Test()

  Dim InxCol As Integer
  Dim InxRow As Integer
  Dim InxTA As Integer
  Dim TArray() As Variant

  ReDim TArray(1 To 10)

  With Sheets("xxxxx")

  For InxTA = 1 To 10
    ' There must be at least two cells in each range if the result is to be an
    ' array.  The access code relies on TArray being a true array of arrays.
    ' If this is not possible, you can test for TArray(N) being an array
    ' or a variable using VarType
    TArray(InxTA) = .Range(.Cells(InxTA, 1), .Cells(InxTA, 12 - InxTA)).Value
  Next

  End With

  For InxTA = 1 To 10
    For InxRow = LBound(TArray(InxTA), 1) To UBound(TArray(InxTA), 1)
      For InxCol = LBound(TArray(InxTA), 2) To UBound(TArray(InxTA), 2)
        Debug.Print TArray(InxTA)(InxRow, InxCol) & " ";
      Next
    Next
    Debug.Print
  Next

End Sub
```

**New material**

I have decided to add an explanation so my answer is complete.

You can set a variant to anything and then set it to something else.  The following may be stupid but it works:

```
Dim V As Variant

V = 5
Debug.Print V
V = "Today"
Debug.Print V
V = Array(1, 2, 3)
Debug.Print V(0) & " " & V(1) & " " & V(2)
```

Consider: `Range( xxx ).Value`

If `xxx` is a single cell, it returns a single variable.  In all other cases it returns a two dimensional array.  The first dimension is for the rows and the second for the columns.  This is the opposite of normal practice but it matches `Cells(R, C).Value`.

I have declared:

```
Dim TArray() As Variant
Redim TArray(1 to 10)
```

So TArray is an array of variants

I then set `TArray(N) = Range( xxx ).Value`

If `xxx` is a single cell, TArray(N) will be a single value.

But if `xxx` is two or more cells, TArray(N) is a two dimensional array.  To access a single cell within TArray, I must specify a element of TArray and then a row and column of the range.  Thus:

```
TArray(Element)(Row, Column)
```

Each element of TArray can have a different size from every other element.  One can be a single variable, another a single row range, another a single column range and yet another a rectangle.

This is difficult to get your head around at first.  No - delete "at first".  Play with this functionality.  Do what I did and load rows, columns and rectangles from one of your worksheets.

Answer (score 2):

All credit to @Tony Dallimore for  `Array or Array`'s idea.  This is offered only as a supliment to his answer.

To load all sheets data into an array use

```
Dim TArray() as Variant
Dim sh as Worksheet

ReDim TArray(1 To ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count)

For each sh in ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    TArray(sh.Index) = sh.UsedRange ' or to get just Column A: sh.UsedRange.Columns(1)
Next
```

Or to load a subset of sheets whose names match a pattern

```
i = 1
For each sh in ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    If sh.Name Like "Region *" Then
         TArray(i) = sh.UsedRange ' or to get just Column A: sh.UsedRange.Columns(1)
         i = i + 1
    End If
Next
```

Again, credit to Tony: if OP feels inclined to accept this, please accept Tony's answer instead

Comment: Useful addition to my answer.  My normal practice is to overload the OP with explanations.  I think this is the first time I have ever said: "Here is a technique.  Use it as you wish."