# How do I set up a "jagged array" in VBA?

Tags: arrays, vba, jagged-arrays

I have a classroom full of kids, each of whom have to list their favorite toys for an assignment.  Some kids only list 1 toy whereas others list more.

How do I create a jagged array such that Kids(x)(y)...where x is the number of kids in my class, and y is the list of toys that they list as their favorites?

Comment: See my answer to [Excel Macro loading Arrays](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8726625/973283) which explains about jagged arrays.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

"Jagged array" is slang for array of arrays. VBA's`Variant` data type can contain just about anything*, including an array. So you make an array of type `Variant`, and assign to each of its elements an array of arbitrary length (i.e. not all of them have to have equal length).

Here's an example:

```
Dim nStudents As Long
Dim iStudent As Long
Dim toys() As Variant
Dim nToys As Long
Dim thisStudentsToys() As Variant

nStudents = 5 ' or whatever

ReDim toys(1 To nStudents) ' this will be your jagged array

For iStudent = 1 To nStudents
    'give a random number of toys to this student (e.g. up to 10)
    nToys = Int((10 * Rnd) + 1)
    ReDim thisStudentsToys(1 To nToys)

    'code goes here to fill thisStudentsToys()
    'with their actual toys

    toys(iStudent) = thisStudentsToys
Next iStudent

' toys array is now jagged.

' To get student #3's toy #7:
MsgBox toys(3)(7)
'will throw an error if student #3 has less than 7 toys
```

<sub>* A notable exception is user-defined types. Variants cannot contain these.</sub>

Comment: When you ReDim the `thisStudentsToys`, is there essentially a new memory location created? I thought arrays in VBA are references. I just want to double check: On the second iteration of the for loop, rewriting the `thisStudentsToys` array does not alter the first index of `toys`? Please let me know if I am not making myself clear. Thank you

Answer (score 7):

You can use a collection of collections

```
Public Sub Test()

    Dim list As New Collection
    Dim i As Integer, j As Integer
    Dim item As Collection
    For i = 1 To 10
        Set item = New Collection
        For j = 1 To i
            item.Add "Kid" & CStr(i) & "Toy" & CStr(j)
        Next j
        list.Add item
    Next i

    Debug.Print "Kid 4, Toy 2 = " & list(4)(2)
End Sub
```

Which outputs `Kid 4, Toy 2 = Kid4Toy2`

Comment: How is a collection of collections, which I'm not familiar with, different from an array of arrays or a jagged array?

Comment: You can add and remove items from a collection, but not from arrays. Also you can access items with a key in addition to an index if needed. Maybe you use the kids name or ID as a key for the collection.

Answer (score 4):

Jean-Francois pointed out that each element can be an array of varying length. I would add that each element can also be of other types and need not be arrays. For example:

```
Dim c as New Collection
Dim a(1 to 5) as Variant

c.Add "a","a"
c.Add "b","b"
a(1) = 5
a(2) = Array(2,3,4)
set a(3) = c
a(4) = "abcd"
a(5) = Range("A1:A4").Value
```

The various child elements can then be referenced depending on the implicit type of each:

a(2)(1) = 3

a(3)(1) = "a"

a(5)(2,1) = whatever is in cell A2.

Answer (score 3):

You could also concatenate the list of toys into eg a pipe-separated string, then use Split to turn the string into an array when needed:

```
Sub UntangleTheString()

Dim sToys As String
Dim aToys() As String
Dim x As Long

sToys = "baseball|doll|yoyo"

aToys = Split(sToys, "|")

For x = LBound(aToys) To UBound(aToys)
    Debug.Print aToys(x)
Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't necessarily need a jagged array to handle your scenario as a 2D array (r, c) will also work.  One row for each child and one column for each present.  The array dimensions will be (# of children, MAX # of presents) and it will just mean that some of the slots will be empty or 0 (depending on your data type).  But at least this way you won't need to redim the array each time you add a present for a child.