# Excel vba - combine multiple arrays into one

Tags: vba, excel

If I have 5 arrays that have same dimension, can I combine them into one array with 5 subarrays.

```
va = ws1.Range("A2", ws1.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)).Value   
vb = ws1.Range("D2", ws1.Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp)).Value    
vc = ws1.Range("F2", ws1.Cells(Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp)).Value    
vd = ws1.Range("C2", ws1.Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp)).Value    
ve = ws1.Range("E2", ws1.Cells(Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp)).Value
```

Can I do this:

```
ReDim vx(1 To UBound(va, 1), 1 To 5, 1 To 1)
vx(1,1,1) = va
vx(1,2,1) = vb
vx(1,3,1) = vc
vx(1,4,1) = vd
vx(1,5,1) = ve
```

Or do I have to do it one element by one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Combining arrays into array is named usually jagged array ([info for C# jagged arrays](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/jagged-arrays) and [How do I set up a "jagged array" in VBA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9435608/how-do-i-set-up-a-jagged-array-in-vba) and [Can you declare jagged arrays in excel VBA directly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19633937/can-you-declare-jagged-arrays-in-excel-vba-directly)), if the number of elements is not the same. In the case below `va` has one element more than `vb` and `vc`:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub TestMe()

    Dim va, vb, vc, vx

    va = Array(1, 2, 3, 4)
    vb = Array(11, 22, 33)
    vc = Array(111, 222, 333)

    ReDim vx(3)
    vx(0) = va
    vx(1) = vb
    vx(2) = vc

    Debug.Print vx(0)(1)
    Debug.Print vx(0)(2)

    Debug.Print vx(1)(1)
    Debug.Print vx(2)(2)

End Sub
```

You simply declare `vx` and you assign `va`, `vb`, `vc` to it as they are. Then you access the elements like this -> `vx(1)(0)`