# How to combine 2D arrays from multiple Excel files into single 2D array?

Tags: vba

Target - to combine multiple 2D arrays from multiple Excel files into single 2D array. I'm first time in coding and VBA.

```
Sub RangeToArray()
Dim s As String, MyFiles As String
Dim i As Long, j As Long, r As Long, m As Long, n As Long
Dim dArray() As Variant, fArray() As Variant
Dim wb As Workbook, rng As Range
        
MyFiles = "path"
s = Dir(MyFiles & "*.xls")
Do While s <> ""

    ReDim fArray(ubounddArray1, ubounddArray2)
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(MyFiles & s, False, True)
    Set rng = wb.Sheets(1).Range("A1:B2")
        dArray = rng.Value
                
        uboundfArray1 = UBound(fArray, 1)
        uboundfArray2 = UBound(fArray, 2)
        ubounddArray1 = UBound(dArray, 1)
        ubounddArray2 = UBound(dArray, 2)

        ReDim Preserve fArray(uboundfArray1, uboundfArray2 + bounddArray2 + 1)
        For m = LBound(dArray, 1) To UBound(dArray, 1)      
            For n = LBound(dArray, 2) To UBound(dArray, 2)  
                fArray(m, uboundfArray2 + n) = dArray(m, n)
            Next n
        Next m
                       
    wb.Close SaveChanges:=False
        
    s = Dir
        
Loop
```

Don't work. Write Run-time error '9':
Subscript out of range.

Comment: You can't `Preserve` a multidimensional array that contains data. Use a bunch of separate arrays or an array of arrays or a list or a dictionary... then join the collections into a single array

Comment: Absinthe, is last dimension of array too?

Comment: You can change only the last dimension, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/redim-statement. Also maybe see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1588913/how-do-i-merge-two-arrays-in-vba or  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51405541/combining-multiple-arrays-in-vba

Comment: Absinthe, fArray(m, uboundfArray2 + n) = dArray(m, n)  is write Run-time error '9': Subscript out of range. How change this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Untested, but this may be one way to approach it:

```vb
Sub RangeToArray()
    
    Dim s As String, MyFiles As String
    Dim fArray() As Variant, arr, i As Long
    Dim numRows As Long, numCols As Long, r As Long, c As Long, rT As Long
    Dim wb As Workbook, colArrays As Collection

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    MyFiles = "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Nezavisimai\Papka2\"
    s = Dir(MyFiles & "*.xls")
    Set colArrays = New Collection
    
    Do While s <> ""
        With Workbooks.Open(MyFiles & s, False, True)
            colArrays.Add .Sheets(1).Range("A1:B2").Value 'add array to collection
            .Close False
        End With
        s = Dir
    Loop
    
    numRows = UBound(colArrays(1), 1)
    numCols = UBound(colArrays(1), 2)  'edit:fixed typo

    ReDim fArray(1 To (numRows*colArrays.Count), 1 to numCols) 
    rT = 0
    'loop over collection and add each item to the final array
    For Each arr In colArrays
        For r = 1 To numRows
            rT = rT + 1
            For c = 1 To numCols
                fArray(rT, c) = arr(r, c)
            Next c
        Next r
    Next arr
    
    Worksheets("Insert").Range("A1") _
          .Resize(UBound(fArray, 1), UBound(fArray, 2)).Value = fArray

End Sub
```

Comment: Tim Williams, your code is work, but your code make it: A1, B1 - 1st row, A2 B2 - 2nd row - after your code start result A1, B1, C1, D1 - 1st row. How Preserve A1,B1 - 3 row, A1,B1 - 5 row,  and A2,B2- 4 row, A2, B2 - 6 row?

Comment: Can you create a screenshot of how the data should look on the final sheet?

Comment: Tim Williams, screenshot:    https://drive.google.com/file/d/1FndxnJj0IoWRegOJKe576M0iXRtCJaU_/view?usp=sharing

Comment: OK I think that should be close now