# excel VBA dynamic size of array-array

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I simply have the issue that I need to create an array with a number of arrays. the problem is that the number of the arrays are only known at runtime.
so, how can initialize (create) the array with the correct size?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You'll have to run some code that figures it out first.

Comment: I guess the key here is ReDim as what @brettdj posted which Re-dimensions array at runtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per Ron's comment, use variables to set your array when it is known.

```
Dim lngRow As Long
Dim lngCol As Long
Dim X()
lngRow = 100
lngCol = 15
ReDim X(1 To lngCol, 1 To lngRow)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I didn't want to use matrix arrays before but it might help me. I need to figure that out. Anyway, I found another question with [well described solutions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9435608/how-do-i-set-up-a-jagged-array-in-vba). Give me some time to understand the difference between those and your solutions. Thank you so far.

Comment: I could find a way to use the matrix array effectively. Thanks for the help.