# How to initialize a multidimensional array variable in vba for excel

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

The [Microsoft site](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y13tek7e.aspx) suggests the following code should work:

`Dim numbers = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}}`

However I get a complile error when I try to use it in an excel VBA module.
The  following does work for a 1D array:

`A = Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)`

However I have not managed to find a way of doing the same for a 2D array.
Any ideas?

Comment: note that the microsoft site's code is initializing a nested array instead of a multi-dim array

Comment: The link on the Microsoft site refers to "Visual Basic' rather than 'Visual Basic for Applications'

Comment: Whenever I'm searching up the documentation for VBA, the first thing I check is if the URL says `office/vba` or `dotnet/visual-basic`. Office VBA is what you're using in Excel. dotnet visual basic is refering to [VB.NET](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Basic_.NET), the language that was made for the .Net framework, a "successor" to [Visual Basic Script](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VBScript).

Answer (score 35):

You can also use a shorthand format leveraging the `Evaluate` function and a static array. In the code below, `varData` is set where `[]` is the shorthand for the `Evaluate` function and the `{...}` expression indicates a static array. Each row is delimited with a `;` and each field delimited with a `,`. It gets you to the same end result as simoco's code, but with a syntax closer to your original question:

```
Sub ArrayShorthand()

    Dim varData As Variant
    Dim intCounter1 As Integer
    Dim intCounter2 As Integer

    ' set the array
    varData = [{1, 2, 3; 4, 5, 6; 7, 8, 9}]

    ' test
    For intCounter1 = 1 To UBound(varData, 1)
        For intCounter2 = 1 To UBound(varData, 2)
            Debug.Print varData(intCounter1, intCounter2)
        Next intCounter2
    Next intCounter1

End Sub
```

Comment: This is a better answer than the accepted because it creates a true two-dimensional array that is accessed using standard `varData(row, col)` notation.

Comment: Yes, this is best.  It is worth pointing out that the square brackets are syntactic sugar for Application.Evaluate (at least I believe so).

Comment: @Robin very cool, I searched high and low for this syntax, thanks!

Comment: @SMeaden Not sure what your point is -- The answer states (repeatedly) that the square brackets are emulating `Evaluate`.

Comment: @ashleedawg : haha, thanks for your feedback.  my comment arose because of something I read in an old COM textbook that states that square brackets emulating `Evaluate` was a COM convention driven of dispid -5  and in fact I explored this later http://exceldevelopmentplatform.blogspot.com/2018/05/vba-use-square-brackets-trick-to.html i.e. it is not unique to Excel.  I admit that without the details the earlier comment above does not add much value there.  Thanks.

Comment: @ashleedawg : Sorry, there were two blog posts,start with this one http://exceldevelopmentplatform.blogspot.com/2018/05/vba-com-dispid-5-gives-vba-square.html

Comment: @Robin Mackenzie I try to apply your code in MS Access. In the line `varData = [{1, 2, 3; 4, 5, 6; 7, 8, 9}]` I get the error `Run-time error '2465':
Microsoft Access cannot find field 1 ",
specified in the expression.`.  Could you tell me what I'm doing wrong?
How to fix the error?

Comment: @eusataf maybe this technique only works for Excel. I never tried it in Access.

Comment: @Robin `[...]` is a shortcut to the `Evaluate` method, which is a part of Excel , and not Access

Comment: the drawback of this syntax is that it doesn't work (to me) spread in 3 separated lines using the " _".  The solution with "array(...)" can do this instead

Comment: @RobinMackenzie fyi though an old post, you might be interested in my alternative approach to your array short cut method via a frequently unknown use of `Application.Index()`

Answer (score 13):

> The Microsoft site suggests...

This suggestion is for VB.NET but not VBA.

For VBA you were in the right direction. You can do this:

```
Dim A as Variant
A = Array(Array(1, 2), Array(3, 4), Array(5, 6))
```

Comment: many thanks I can then access members of the array using X=A(1)(2)

Comment: In this case, how to get the different sizes ?

Comment: Note that is creates a [jagged array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9435608/11683) (a 1D array of arrays), not a 2D array.

Answer (score 3):

**Alternative via `Application.Index()`**

Extending on Dmitriv Pavliv's use of a jagged array (and as alternative to Robin Mackenzie's short hand approach), you can go a step further by applying `Application.Index()` on this array of arrays (with identical number of elements each) - *note the double zero arguments!*:

```
Sub Get2DimArray()
    Dim arr() As Variant
    'a) build array of arrays (aka as jagged array)
    arr = Array(Array(1, 2, 4), Array(4, 5, 6), Array(7, 8, 9))
    'b) make it 2-dimensional
    arr = Application.Index(arr, 0, 0)
End Sub
```

**Results in**
a 2-dim arr(1 To 3, 1 To 3), where

```
   * Row 1 ~> 1|2|4
   * Row 2 ~> 4|5|6
   * Row 3 ~> 7|8|9
```

**Related link**

Further reading regarding [Some pecularities of the `Application.Index()` function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51688593/excel-vba-insert-new-first-column-in-datafield-array-without-loops-or-api-call/51714153#51714153)

Answer (score 1):

So here you generate the array without anything on it, just by telling its dimensions.
Dimension is X+1 because 0 counts as a position in the array.

```
Dim MyArray(X, X) As Integer
```

Then you fill it by doing for exemple

```
MyArray (0,0) = 1
MyArray (0,1) = 2
MyArray (1,0) = 3
MyArray (1,1) = 4
```

...

And so on.

If you want a more convenient way of filling it you can use For Cycles if there is a inherent logic to the numbers you are filling it with.

Answer (score 0):

In case the size is unknown until run time.

```
Dim nRows As Integer, nCols As Integer
...
Dim yourArray() As Integer
ReDim yourArray(1 to nRows, 1 to nCols) 'One base initialisation
'ReDim yourArray(0 to nRows - 1, 0 to nCols - 1) 'Zero base initialisation
```

Then you can initialise (or access) the grid as:

```
yourArray(1, 1) = ... 'set first cell
```