# Constant 2 dimensional array Access VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access, multidimensional-array, constants

Is it possible to create a constant two dimensional array in VBA using access only? 
I have Tried:

```
Const s1 As String = [{"a","b","c";"1","2","3"}]
```

from [How to initialize a multidimensional array variable in vba for excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24584088/how-to-initialize-a-multidimensional-array-variable-in-vba-for-excel) and

```
Const s2 as variant = array(array("a","b","c"),array("1","2","3"))
```

But neither work. I checked to see if they work as regular declarations.

```
Dim s1 As String = [{"a","b","c";"1","2","3"}]
```

fails, and it seems to be because i am not using Excel.

```
dim s2 as variant = array(array("a","b","c"),array("1","2","3"))
```

succeeds.

Comment: VBA doesn't let you assign a value on the `Dim` line like `vb.net` does. First you `Dim` it, then you assign the values on a second line.

Comment: Ah dang, i didn't notice that one because i was looking for two dimensional arrays in my query.

Comment: this is not an exactly duplicate, because it ms-access and not excel-vba  I have a solution for the excel-vba question.  voted to re-open.