# Manually assign a 2D array with 1 entry

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to assign a 2D array by just setting the array equal to an excel range (*`n Rows X 1 Column`*).

When (*`n = 1`*) this just gives me a value, so I want to manually assign the array in this case. I tried the below but it populates with a `Error 2015`

```
Function Get_Params(ws As Worksheet, LR As Long, Target As Range) As Variant

Dim Temp As Worksheet: Set Temp = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Temp")
Dim LR2 As Long

ws.Range("D1:D" & LR).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
Temp.Range("U1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

Temp.Range("U1").RemoveDuplicates 1, xlYes
    LR2 = Temp.Range("U" & Temp.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    If LR2 = 2 Then
        Get_Params = [{Temp.Range("U2"), 1}] '<-- ISSUE HERE
    Else
        Get_Params = Temp.Range("U2:U" & LR2).Value
    End If

    Temp.Range("U1").EntireColumn.ClearContents

End Function
```

The goal is to do something like

```
For i = LBound(Get_Params, 1) to UBound(Get_Params, 1)
    'Do something with Get_Params(i, 1)
Next i
```

---

I tried to manually assign the array via [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24584088/how-to-initialize-a-multidimensional-array-variable-in-vba-for-excel/37584058) solution utilizing the `Evaluate` function, but this yields my error. I have also tried to use `Get_Params = [{Temp.Range("U2").Value, 1}]` and receive same error

How can I manually assign this array to allow me to go through the above loop without error?

Comment: What sort of object is `Get_Params = [{Temp.Range("U2"), 1}]` supposed to construct? A 1-based 2-dimensional array whose sole value is `Ger_Params(1,1) = Temp.Range("U1")`?

Comment: @JohnColeman The same type of object that would be generated with `Get_Params = Temp.Range("A1:A10").Value`. The first element would have 10 values, and the second would have 1 value. The only difference between the array set is that one will strictly have 1 value in each element and the other will be a function of `LR2`

Comment: My goal is to tackle that issue here in the function rather have to recreate the exact same code on my main sub that does the same thing for the array vs the value I.E. `If Array Then Do This, Else Do The Exact Same Thing for Value`. If I can force it to match the 2D array, my main macro needs no modification.

Comment: `Get_Params = Temp.Range("A1:A10").Value` Has 10 values, each of which is accessed with 2 indices.

Comment: Yes, @JohnColeman. So how do I get `Get_Params` to have 1 value with 2 indices where the 2nd index is 1 and the 1st index is the value in `U2`is the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could replace

```
Get_Params = [{Temp.Range("U2"), 1}]
```

By

```
Dim returnValue As Variant

'... then in the if statement:

ReDim returnValue(1 to 1, 1 to 1)
returnValue(1,1) = Temp.Range("U2").Value
Get_Params = returnValue
```