# How do i manually declare a two dimentional array in vba?

Tags: excel, vba

in python it is possible to declare a list in a list for example like this
l=[[1,0,0],[0,1,0],[0,0,1]]
how do i do the same but in VBA excel

Comment: `l = Array(Array(1, 0, 0), Array(0, 1, 0), Array(0, 0, 1))`

Comment: Dim My2DArray(1 To 3, 1 To 3) As Integer

Comment: @Warcupine - that's a 1D jagged array, not a 2D array.

Comment: @BigBen But it is the vba equivalent of the python list in the question.

Comment: @Warcupine - fair. Maybe semantics at this point. Technically if OP wants a 2D array in VBA, then Brian's suggestion may be better. But either should work.

Comment: @bigben Yeah, his list is a jagged list it would be access `l[0][0]`, mine would be `l(0)(0)` and Brian's would be `l(0, 0)` (or 1, 1 with his indexing). I don't think core python has a true multidimensional one, I've only seen it in numpy, but I'm not sure about that.

Comment: @Warcupine - exactly, that hits the nail right on the head.

Comment: It depends if this 2D array is to interact with a worksheet table or just be processed within VBA. There are rules (like it cannot be a jagged array) if you are to interact with Excel.

Answer (score 5):

*Declaring* an array in VBA is different from initializing its contents (unlike python).

You declare a variable to be a 2D array of size `N`, `M` with

```
Dim a(1 to N, 1 to M) as Variant
```

but this creates a fixed sized array and not a dynamic array. It is better to declare an array as follows

```
Dim a() as Variant
ReDim a(1 to N, 1 to M)
```

and to fill the array with values you need a double loop, or assigning elements manually

```
a(1,1) = ...
a(1,2) = ...
```

Notice that I declared arrays that are 1-based, instead of 0-based (first element is a(1,1), and not a(0,0)) because when reading in a table from an Excel worksheet with

```
a = Range("A2").Resize(N,M).Value
Debug.Print a(3,1)
```

it creates such an array.

Note that it is possible to declare a dynamic array and fill it in with jagged form (array of arrays) using the following code

```
Dim a() as Variant
a = Array( Array(1,2,3), Array(4,5,6), Array(7,8,9) )
```

which you have access to in VBA with the following form

```
Debug.Print a(2)(0)
' 7
```

Notice that they arrays produced by the `Array()` command are 0-based with indexes varying between `0..N-1`. Additionally, since the above is jagged array (array of arrays), the elements are accessed using sequential indexers as in `a(i)(j)` instead of `a(i,j)`

So it really depends on how you want to use the 2D array to decide how to best declare it.

Comment: Just be aware that with VBA you can set negative value for the start and end of a dimension.  i.e. Dim myArray(-10 to -5) is perfectly legal.

Comment: @BigBen - thanks, fixed.

Comment: Warning when using `Array()`. The arrays produced by `Array()` are also `Variant` type. If you need an array of some other type you have to use one of the other methods of declaring and filling the array.

Comment: @Toddleson - true, and hence I always use `Variant` for all arrays except when required otherwise, like with `VBA.Split()`.

Comment: well my use is i defined an arrray this way { Public a() as variant } and set it up in a public worksheet for example{ a=array(1,2,3) } but then for some reason everything stored inside gets lost or rather i cant acces it in another sub (the other sub is in a classmodule)

Comment: @ghassenboughanmi If the array `a` is declared inside a function then when the function goes out of scope the contents are lost. So declare the array as a global in a module, or as a member variable to a worksheet (under the worksheet code, but outside the function).

Comment: It might be of some interest that you can transform the jagged array (assigned via `a=Array( Array(1,2,3), Array(4,5,6), Array(7,8,9) )`)  into a 2-dim array simply via `a= Application.Index(a, 0, 0)`. - See my related answer [How to initialize a multidimensional array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24584088/how-to-initialize-a-multidimensional-array-variable-in-vba-for-excel/66969472#66969472 @JAlex