# "Cant assign to array error" when Populating a Jagged Array with String Arrays

Tags: excel, vba, text-files, arrays, jagged-arrays

I want to have a Jagged Array with two layers: 1) being a number, 2) being an Array of Strings so I can easily reference an array based off an index value. The point of this is to get the content of a text file so that each index in the jagged array is a row of the text file (layer 1 = index, layer 2 = row). These rows are populated by strings of course.

Without any adjustments, the text file has unwanted space in between strings in each row. I want the Array of strings to not include any of the wasted space (`"Hello       how are you   "` --> `["hello","how","are","you"]`).

I do this though the `Trim` function and the `Split` function. `Trim` removes all but the delimiting spaces; `Split` produces the Array of Strings I want for that line. My issue is getting the array into the Jagged Array as well as creating an array without knowing its length ahead of time, as I have not `Split` the row of text yet.

Below is my code. When I use a variant instead of a String as my second layer I get another error which I cant seem to solve. *Note: the string array which contains the text file information is* `tempString()`

### ***UPDATED CODE:**

---

so you can test this, use `tempString = ("    test tempstring ", "", "   test test test", "    "," test    ", "")`

```
Private Sub createGCStruct(ByRef tempString() As String)
' note many parameters are not included.
' also, this would be a function producing a structure, but for now I just need this to properly create a
' jagged array.
' set variables

    Dim tempString2() As String
    ReDim tempString2(UBound(tempString()))

    Dim j As Integer

    Dim jaggArray() As Variant                '*****outer layer of the jagged array*****
    ReDim jaggArray(UBound(tempString()) + 1)
    Dim stringST() As String                  '*****inner layer of the jagged array*****

    Dim tempString4() As String

' set initial values of structure
' ...more code...
' capture structure information from textfile array

' A) remove unnecessary spaces from existing Array
    For j = LBound(tempString()) To UBound(tempString())
        ' check to see if line is zero length string
        If tempString(j) = "" Then
        ' what you don't see are my commented out, futile attempts at
        ' solving this problem; just know that they exist
            Erase stringST
            stringST = tempString(j)
            jaggArray(j + 1) = stringST
        ' trim excesive spacing
        Else
            tempString2(j) = Trim(tempString(j))
            Erase stringST
            stringST = Split(tempString2(j), " ")
            jaggArray(j + 1) = stringST
        End If
    Next j
    'Below is me testing to see if this works'
    tempString4 = jaggArray(1)
    MsgBox tempString4(0), vbExclamation, "test"

' B) Add sections from array to structure
'... more code...
End Sub
```

Comment: Please provide a [self-contained example](http://www.sscce.org/) that will allow us to reproduce the problem. Else it's really difficult to help you. In the meantime, a couple of tips: What you want is a `Function`, not a `Sub`, as in `Private Function createGCStruct(...,...,[get rid of the last ByRef argument]) As gcBStruct`. Also, the `Erase stringST` are useless and can be removed.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9435608/how-do-i-set-up-a-jagged-array-in-vba

Comment: Also see this article for a `Split` function that treats multiple successive delimiters as one: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa155763%28office.10%29.aspx

Comment: Is it possible to use a collection or dictionary instead to house the string arrays? I think one of my main issues is properly utilizing `stringST` as a "temporary" string that will simply place the string array into the Jagged Array. I can't define the size of the `stringST` array or set the individual elements in the split string values of each row into `stringST`. Furthermore, since I reuse `stringST`, I want to ensure I clear all prior values. What should I do in this case?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisCorbett I updated the code, you should be able to produce the problem. I kept the `Erase StringST` (for now) to maintain the originality of the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can see that the "Can't assign to array" error occurs in the part of your code where you attempt to deal with the `Split` function's weird bugfeature behaviour whereby splitting an empty string `Split("")` returns a String(0 to -1) array that is utterly unusable.

The "Can't assign to array" error is caused by this line:

```
stringST = tempString(j)
```

The thing on the left, `stringST`, is an array. The thing on the right, `tempString(j)`, isn't. (It's *one element* from the `tempString` array.) You can't assign a non-array to an array, hence the error.

What you can do is define an array that contains a single element, an empty string:

```
Dim emptyStringArrayPlaceholder() As String
ReDim emptyStringArrayPlaceholder(0 To 0)
```

And then use that as placeholder for empty strings:

```
stringST = emptyStringArrayPlaceholder
```

Here's how I would clean up your code:

```
Private Sub createGCStruct(ByRef tempString() As String)

    Dim jaggArray() As Variant                '*****outer layer of the jagged array*****

    jaggArray = splitStringArrayElements(tempString)

    'Below is me testing to see if this works'
    tempString4 = jaggArray(1)
    MsgBox tempString4(0), vbExclamation, "test"

' B) Add sections from array to structure
'... more code...
End Sub
```

where I make use of this function:

```
Private Function splitStringArrayElements(tempString() As String) As Variant()
    Dim j As Long
    Dim trimmedString As String
    Dim jaggArray() As Variant
    ReDim jaggArray(LBound(tempString()) To UBound(tempString()))
    Dim emptyStringArrayPlaceholder() As String
    ReDim emptyStringArrayPlaceholder(0 To 0)

    For j = LBound(tempString()) To UBound(tempString())
        trimmedString = Trim(tempString(j))
        If trimmedString = "" Then
            jaggArray(j) = emptyStringArrayPlaceholder
        Else
            jaggArray(j) = Split(trimmedString, " ")
        End If
    Next j

    splitStringElements = jaggArray
End Function
```

Comment: Great explanation Jean!

Comment: One thing, and I'm not sure if this was because you misunderstood what I was aiming for, was that with your solution the String Arrays in JaggArray still contain repetitive spaces/blanks in between words. I solved this by using a different version of split: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa155763%28office.10%29.aspx

Comment: Yes, well, I did give you that very link in my comment to your question above. My answer addressed the issue you specified in your question: "*My issue is getting the array into the Jagged Array...*".

Comment: ^Lol, you did. Sorry about that mate.