# What's difference between working with arrays declared as Dim Array() as Variant and Dim Array as Variant in VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

What's difference between two declarations `Dim Array_1() as Variant` and `Dim Array_2 as Variant` in VBA ?

If I then create arrays using above declarations :

```
Array_1 = Range("A1:A10")
Array_2 = Range("A1:A10")
```

in locals windows I see different descriptions for Array_1 and Array_2. I seems that Array_2  contain values of undefined type. Could I `ReDim` `Array_2` ?

Comment: Simply put:
Dim Array() as variant is creating an array containing values that are of the type Variant
Dim Array as variant is just creating a variable that can contain a variant value which may also be an array (but really can be almost anything).

Comment: See also [How do I set up a “jagged array” in VBA?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9435608/119775)

Comment: Also, Array is an existing function in VBA, so actually `dim Array as variant` won't work. Try something like `Dim arrayTest as variant`.

Comment: Unless you expand your question, the answer is just going to be, "One's an array, and the other isn't."

Comment: [Here](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/passingandreturningarrays.htm) is one of the differences. If you want to pass an "array" of any type to a function, you pass a single `Variant` instead of an array of `Variant`s. In the latter case, you have to pass an array of `Variant` objects, while in the former you can pass an array of any type. In addition, arrays are passed by reference while variables are passed by value.

Answer (score -1):

```
Dim Arraytest() as Variant
```

Declare's a variable called Arraytest which is setup as an array
The above can be used like below

```
ReDim Arraytest(9)
```

or

```
ReDim Arraytest(1 To 10)
```

To setup an array of 10 values - Arraytest(0) to Arraytest(9) in the first case and Arraytest(1) to Arraytest(10) in the second case.

---

As opposed to :

---

```
Dim Arraytest as Variant
```

Declare's a variable called Arraytest which is setup as a single varaible - note the second code can not be used as an array

Note: Array can not be used as a variable name - used Arraytest in the above

Comment: @R3uK 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 is 10 values? why did you change redim Array(10) to 9? as "0" is counted as 1?

Comment: Yup, there is indeed 10 values between 0 and 9, like there is 10 between 1 and 10. I corrected it as your next line was pretty clear about this.

Comment: *can not be used as an array*... yet `Dim Array as Variant : ReDim Array(1 To 10)` works fine.

Comment: Variant can be anything - even an array! `Dim arrayTest As Variant : arrayTest = Array(1, 2, 3)` This works fine.

Comment: Did you actually try this code? [Array](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa262675(v=vs.60).aspx) is a VBA function, and `Dim Array() as Variant`, with or without parentheses gives a compile error..

Comment: @99moorem Better, but still not ok. The second code **can** be used as an array, as a variant **can** hold arrays.