# How do I interpret this array? (VBA Excel)

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

When stepping through code in Developer mode in Excel I see an array in VBA like so:

```
arrData(x)(y,z)
```

Is this a 2-dimensional array (the (y,z) part) stored inside an array (the (x) part)?

How do I access a particular element within the array and test if the value equals something I'm interested in?

```
If arrData(1)(2,3) = "orange" Then
End If
```

My above code yields Run-time error '9': Subscript out of range.  The max value of x and y is 1, and the max value of z is 100.

Comment: If the max value of x and y is 1, don't try to use a 2 for the y value.  `arrData(1)(1,3)`

Comment: Other than that, you've got it right

Comment: The first array index by default starts at 0.

Comment: @Jules not always, but likely.  It depends on how the array was filled.  It could also depend on how the array was declared.  It may be ArrData(1to1)

Comment: Correct, that's why I said by default :). EDIT: to be save use lbound and ubound to check min/max index.

Comment: Thank you for confirming my understanding!

Answer (score 0):

This is called a jagged array. Essentially it is an array inside an array. These can be implemented in VBA (as you discovered) and can be called just like a regular array.

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9435608/how-do-i-set-up-a-jagged-array-in-vba) here on SO explains it nicely.