# How do i dim values in an array as arrays?

Tags: vba, excel

just out of curiosity.

is it possible to dim values in an array as their own individual array?

```
Sub test()

Dim ar(5) As Variant

ar(1) = a
ar(2) = b
ar(3) = c
ar(4) = d
ar(5) = e

For i = 1 To UBound(ar)
    Dim ar(i) As Variant '<---doesn't work :(
Next i


End Sub
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I set up a "jagged array" in VBA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9435608/how-do-i-set-up-a-jagged-array-in-vba)

Comment: @A.S.H - You should have found that **before** I wrote an answer! :D

Comment: @A.S.H, doh, me too.

Comment: @YowE3K and vice-versa! :P anyway why delete your answer, I liked the "mixture".

Comment: @Ambie same... :)

Comment: @A.S.H I always worry about having an answer to a question that I then mark as "duplicate" - it seems like I'm just chasing rep points.  (But I undeleted it anyway.)

Comment: @YowE3K everyone is chasing rep points, it's almost the only stimulator to write good answers isn't it? It's only about not overdoing :)

Comment: @A.S.H I'm not chasing rep points - the more points you have, the more SO housekeeping that you are expected to do - and I'm **lazy** so don't want to have to do it! ;-)

Comment: haha, thanks @A.S.H. jagged array, got to learn a new term today :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're after a matrix style array, then you could just define a multi-dimensional array:

```
Dim ar(5, x) As Variant
```

But it seems as though you want a jagged array, ie an array of arrays. In that case you just assign an `Array()` Variant to each element of your array:

```
Dim ar(5) As Variant
ar(0) = Array(1, 2, 3)
```

And the syntax to access the 'sub-elements' would be `ar(x)(y)`:

```
Debug.Print ar(0)(1)
```

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to set one (or more) position of a `Variant` array to be an array:

```
Sub test()

    Dim ar(5) As Variant
    Dim ar1(1 To 4) As Variant

    ar1(1) = 5
    ar1(2) = "x"
    Set ar1(3) = ActiveSheet
    ar1(4) = 10

    ar(1) = "a"
    ar(2) = "b"
    ar(3) = ar1
    ar(4) = "d"
    ar(5) = "e"

    Debug.Print ar(1)
    Debug.Print ar(3)(1)
    Debug.Print ar(3)(3).Name

End Sub
```