# several non contiguous columns into array

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I try to load as efficiently as possible 4 columns to an array.
I tried

```
dim ar
ar = sheet1.Range("C2:C2681,G2:G2681,J2:J2681,T2:T2681")
```

but only the first column is loaded into the array.
I also tried

```
    ar = .Range("C2:T" & lastRow)
    ar = Application.Index(ar, , Array(1, 5, 19))
```

but that gives me a type mismatch error.

Any clever trick for this purpose ?

Comment: Put them into 4 different arrays.  If you want to then loop them and put them in one array.

Comment: Simple and efficient indeed.

Comment: @ScottCraner Can you make it an answer ?

Comment: In a meeting, on my phone.  I like jeeped's answer better anyways.

Comment: @ScottCraner I gotchu my man, added one with the type of answer you were thinking of

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could always store those columns within a [jagged array](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9436309/2727437), an array of arrays. The syntax is actually pretty easy in VBA; you can store all the `.Value`s of a range (in the form of an array) inside of another (previously dimmed) array.

When you're working with a range that includes several sub-ranges (contiguous or not), you can access them separately by looping on that range's [`.Areas` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.areas).

The only thing that you have to be careful about is the indices because the syntax is a little funky and in your particular example you don't start with the first row.

```
Option Explicit

Sub NonContiguousRanges()

    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Range("C2:C20, G2:G20, J2:J20, T2:T20")

    Dim jagged As Variant
    ReDim jagged(1 To rng.areas.count)

    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To rng.areas.count
        jagged(i) = rng.areas(i).Value2
    Next i


    '=-~ examples of accessing the values ~-='

    'first value, C2
    MsgBox jagged(1)(1, 1)

    'last  value, T20
    MsgBox jagged(4)(19, 1)
    MsgBox jagged(UBound(jagged))(UBound(jagged(UBound(jagged))), 1)

End Sub
```

I mean just look at all those `UBound`s... gave me a bit of a headache just getting it right!

Answer (score 2):

ReDim with Preserve will only allow you to modify the last rank but you could shift the array elements' values first.

```
dim ar as variant, i as long

ar = sheet1.Range("C2:T2681").value

for i=lbound(ar, 1) to ubound(ar, 1)
    ar(i, 2) = ar(i, 5)   'move column G to 2nd
    ar(i, 3) = ar(i, 8)   'move column J to 3rd
    ar(i, 4) = ar(i, 18)  'move column T to 4th
next i

redim preserve ar(lbound(ar, 1) to ubound(ar, 1), lbound(ar, 2) to 4)
```