# VBA Traverse through each non-empty element of 2-d array

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to perform some action on each element of a 2D array where the second dimension of the array varies on each of the first dimensional elements. I would like the loop to skip empty elements.

A 1D array would make it run through the loop without wasting any time on empty elements of the array, but I would like to use a 2D array to make it easier to associate data into a certain group and make the code easier to modify later by somebody else if needed. The 1D array runs much faster than the 2D array.

```
Application.EnableCancelKey = xlDisabled

On Error Resume Next

For i = 0 To UBound(somearray,1)    
    For j = 0 To UBound(somearray,2)
        perform some action on somearray(i,j)    
    Next j
Next i
```

It should be noted that I do get a subscript 9 out of range error without the `On Error Resume Next`. I assume this is because it is attempting to perform an action on something that doesn't exist. It works as intended but is just slower.

I apologize if the question is trivial. I wasn't able to find an answer to this and I know nothing about VBA.

Comment: How do you define `somearray`? Think we need a bit more code. Nothing obviously wrong with the code you've posted.

Comment: What are the lower bounds of the array? Also, `On Error Resume Next` when used like that is just awful. Errors should be fixed or at least handled, not suppressed.

Comment: Can you elaborate on both part of *where the second dimension of the array varies on each of the first dimensional elements. I would like the loop to skip empty elements.*?  I don't want to be wrong in assuming where the empty elements are (,1 or ,2)

Comment: If your array indeed has [different number of elements in the second dimension](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9435608/11683), you cannot access it as `somearray(i,j)`, but rather as `somearray(i)(j)`. If your array is a normal array where some of the last elements in each row are `Empty`, then use `IsEmpty()` to not "loop over them".

Comment: I managed to figure it out and the comments were helpful. For some reason IsEmpty() didn't work for me but = "" did.

Answer (score 2):

Remove `On Error Resume Next`, and don't hard-code the lower bounds:

```
Dim currentRow As Long
For currentRow = LBound(somearray, 1) To UBound(somearray, 1)
    Dim currentColumn As Long
    For currentColumn = LBound(somearray, 2) To UBound(somearray, 2)
        DoSomething somearray(currentRow, currentColumn)
    Next
Next
```

If you got your 2D array from a `Range`, it's a 1-based `Variant` array, so subscript `0` is *out of range*.