How to create a dictionary that contains other dictionaries when we don't know their number at the beginning of the program in vba
I have the following code:
Sub Generate_report()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim kamagiData As Worksheet
    Dim incomesData As Worksheet
    
    Dim i As Long, lst As Long
    Dim currentRow As Long
    Dim currentTime As Variant
    Dim currentKamag As String
    Dim currentHour As Long
    
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    Set kamagiData = Sheets("Kamagi")
    Set incomesData = Sheets("Dane wjazdy")
    
    Set hours = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Dim kamags As Dictionary
    
    
    With kamagiData
        lst = .Cells(.Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        For i = 2 To lst
            Set kamags = New Dictionary
            currentTime = .Cells(i, 11).Value
            currentHour = Hour(currentTime)
            currentKamag = .Cells(i, 14).Value
            If Not hours.exists(currentHour) Then
                hours.Add currentHour, kamags
            End If
            'If Not hours(currentHour).exists(currentKamag) Then
                'hours(currentHour).Add currentKamag, 1
            'Else
                'hours(currentHour).Item(currentKamag) = hours(currentHour).Item(currentKamag) + 1
            'End If
            Debug.Print (currentHour)
            Debug.Print (hours(currentHour))
            Debug.Print (currentKamag)
            'Debug.Print (hours(currentHour).Item(currentKamag))
        Next i
    End With
    
    'Po utworzeniu odpowiednich słowników należy uzupełnić odpowiednie pola w tabeli, najpierw czyszcząc je z poprzednich wersji
    'Dodać przycisk czyszczenia raportów
    'Dodać instrukcję
    'Obsłużyć liczenie wjazdów/wyjazdów z yardu
    
End Sub

Its operating principle was to be as follows: In a loop, I check the table rows in the Kamagi sheet, extract the time from the date entered in column K, and the driver number, contained in column N. Then I need to create a division thanks to which I will be assigned the number of occurrences of the driver number in a given hour. The idea is to create a dictionary in which the keys will be the extracted hours, and the values ​​will be dictionaries containing driver - number of occurrences pairs. I have no problem creating a dictionary with hours, the problem starts when I try to add a new dictionary as a value to which I could add drivers and increase the counter of their occurrences. I am trying to do it in this line:
If Not hours.exists(currentHour) Then
  hours.Add currentHour, kamags
End If

Unfortunately, no matter what I try, I keep getting errors of all kinds. I have no idea how to properly initialize the dictionary so that later in the code I can operate on the dictionary element as a separate dictionary. I would be very grateful for any help on this topic.

If someone has a better solution, I would also be all ears; however, the closest thing that comes to mind is abandoning the dictionary aspect and creating a jagged array (collection of collections):  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9435608/how-do-i-set-up-a-jagged-array-in-vba

Dictionary of Dictionaries

Sub GenerateReport()
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    Dim wsKamagi As Worksheet: Set wsKamagi = wb.Sheets("Kamagi")
    Dim wsIncomes As Worksheet: Set wsIncomes = wb.Sheets("Dane wjazdy")
    
    Dim dict As Object: Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    
    With wsKamagi
        
        Dim LastRow As Long: LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        
        Dim i As Long, cHour As Long, cKamag As String
        
        For i = 2 To LastRow
            cHour = Hour(.Cells(i, "K").Value)
            If Not dict.Exists(cHour) Then
                Set dict(cHour) = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
            End If
            cKamag = CStr(.Cells(i, "N").Value)
            dict(cHour)(cKamag) = dict(cHour)(cKamag) + 1
        Next i
    
    End With
    
    Dim oKey As Variant, iKey As Variant
    
    Debug.Print "Hour", "Kamag", "Occur."
    
    For Each oKey In dict.Keys
        Debug.Print "Outer - " & oKey
        For Each iKey In dict(oKey).Keys
            Debug.Print , "Inner " & iKey, dict(oKey)(iKey)
        Next iKey
    Next oKey
                 
    ' ???
    'Po utworzeniu odpowiednich slowników nalezy uzupelnic odpowiednie pola w tabeli, najpierw czyszczac je z poprzednich wersji
    'Dodac przycisk czyszczenia raportów
    'Dodac instrukcje
    'Obsluzyc liczenie wjazdów/wyjazdów z yardu
    
End Sub

Result
Hour          Kamag         Occur.
Outer - 12
              Inner A        2 
              Inner C        1 
Outer - 13
              Inner B        2 
              Inner A        1 
              Inner C        1 
Outer - 14
              Inner B        1 
              Inner A        1 
              Inner C        1 

